# Most efficiently removing the n-th row of tab-delimited txt

Tags: python, file, csv

I have a tab-delimited txt file.

I want to remove n-th row of tab-delimited txt.

I will assign like

```
n = 1
```

then the program will remove just the first row of the file.

If the program does it without even reading the whole input file, then it would be fantastic.

I tried to learn from one of my previous questions:

[Concatenate tab-delimited txt files vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24722449/concatenate-tab-delimited-txt-files-vertically)

This question was vertically concatenating two tab-delimited txt files. So I thought reversing this process will do something similar for me. But I couldn't find how to do it.

I also tried many other stackoverflow answers.

But they are mostly 'removing lines that have specific phrase' rather than 'removing n-th line'

([How to delete a line from a text file using the line number in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17747522/how-to-delete-a-line-from-a-text-file-using-the-line-number-in-python), [Deleting a specific line in a file (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710067/deleting-a-specific-line-in-a-file-python), [Deleting a line from a file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947833/deleting-a-line-from-a-file-in-python))

Comment: Unless the lines are all the same length, read all lines and print all of them except the one you want to remove.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to delete a line from a text file using the line number in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17747522/how-to-delete-a-line-from-a-text-file-using-the-line-number-in-python)

Comment: @tripleee Although that question's title says about deleting using line number, that question isn't actually. That question is explicitly assigning "phrase = 'the dog barked'" and deleting lines with that phrase.

Comment: @tripleee The input file's lines have same length. In other words, all rows have the same number of columns. Then is it possible not to read all lines and remove n-th row?

Comment: Then it's possible to do it more efficiently by seeking to that particular offset and rewrite the file.  But unless you can rewrite with a dummy record (or a real record of data) and leave the remainder of the file intact, I don't think it will be worth the effort.

Comment: Several of the answers to the proposed duplicate show you how to replace a line given its offset in the file.  The accepted solution has a comment (by yours truly) showing how to adapt it.  The `mmap` solution shows some promise to be faster but is significantly more complex.

Comment: But by "same length" I mean the same number of bytes on each line.  (It would not be a valid TSV file if it had a variable number of fields.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) for this. Here no Python for-loop is involved so it should be fast:

```
from itertools import islice

n = 4
with open('file.txt') as f, open('out.txt', 'w') as out:
    out.writelines(islice(f, n-1)) #write the lines before the nth line
    out.writelines(islice(f, 1, None)) #write the rest of the lines except nth
```

Comment: Shouldn’t there be an `n` instead of the `1` in your last line?

Comment: @igor No, it should be `1` as the file object is already sliced up to (n-1)th line. Now we need to start from 2nd index(1) to ignore the nth line.

Answer (score 1):

```
lineToRemove = 7

f = open("yourfile.txt","r")
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()

f = open("yourfile.txt","w")
linesInFile = 0
for line in lines:
    linesInFile = linesInFile + 1
    if linesInFile != lineToRemove:
        f.write(line)
f.close()
```

Edit: By using `del` and omitting explicit `open` and `close` we can reduce the code:

```
lines = file("yourfile.txt", "r").readlines()
del lines[6]
file("yourfile.txt", "w").writelines(lines)
```

Please note that `del lines[6]` removes the 7th line because the index begins with zero. So, here's a convenient function we could use:

```
def deleteLine(filename, lineToRemove):
    lines = file(filename, "r").readlines()
    del lines[lineToRemove-1]
    file(filename, "w").writelines(lines)
```

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly. However, does this program reads whole input file? The input file's lines have same length. In other words, all rows have the same number of columns. Then is it possible not to read all lines and remove n-th row?

Comment: How is this efficient in any way?