# Python Pickle - 2 questions

Tags: python, pickle

I am using python pickle to maintain a contact list. I have 2 questions:

1. After a new person is added, I don't see the whole list with all the persons is printed. only the new person is printed. what is wrong with the code?
2. If I am going to delete one contact, how can I make the change to local file?

The code:

```
import pickle

class contact:
    person= {};    
    def add(self, name,contact):
        self.person[name] = contact;
        store2file(self.person);
        #print(self.contactlist);        
    def delete(self,name):
        del self.person[name];
        #print(self.person);  
    def modify(self,name,contact):
        self.person[name] = contact;
        store2file(self.person);  

def store2file(person):
    mycontactfile = 'contactlist.data';
    f = open(mycontactfile,'wb');
    pickle.dump(person,f);
    f.close();

    f = open(mycontactfile,'rb');
    storedcontact = pickle.load(f);
    print (storedcontact);

def main():
    mycontact = contact();
    option = input('Pls select option: 1 Add; 2 delete; 3 update: ');
    if option == '1':
        name = input('Enter the name: ');
        contactNo = input('Enter the contact number: ');
        mycontact.add(name,contactNo);
        store2file(mycontact);

    elif option =='2':
        name = input('Enter the name: ');
        mycontact.delete(name);
    elif option =='3':
        name = input('Enter the name: ');
        contactNo = input('Enter the contact number: ');
        mycontact.modify(name,contactNo);
    else:
        print('Pls select proper option');

main()
```

Comment: Why exactly do you __read__ the contact file in a method called `store2file`?

Answer (score 1):

You are writing only the new person to the file overwriting existing data. You could write a list to the file (always reading the list and appending the new value before writing) to get the behavior you seem to want.

The workflow should be like this:

- read current list from file
- change stuff (add contact, remove contact)
- maybe change more stuff ...
- write list back to file

It is also possible (but more complex) to do it without a list:

- append to the file as proposed by 'Guy' using `'a'` instead of `'w'` and/or `pickle.dump()` multiple times using the same file handler
- `pickle.load()` multiple times on such a file until an `EOFError` occurs

To delete an entry from such a file you have to load every entry and save all the entries you still want back to the file (like `filter()`).

Comment: IF I only want to use Pickle instead of list, can it be implemented?

Comment: I added a method to do this in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

from python documentation http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html:

> 'w' for only writing (an existing file with the same name will be erased), and 'a' opens the file for appending;

to remove a contact, fine its line and delete it from the file, see [Deleting a specific line in a file (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710067/deleting-a-specific-line-in-a-file-python)

Comment: Thanks. it seems a is not applicable to Pickle? did not miss something?