# Delete a line from a file after reading python

Tags: python, line

how to delete/remove a line from a .txt file after reading or printing

```
for x in open("words.txt",'r'):
print x
# Here i want to delete the line after printing and continue the loop
```

Can someone help me ?

Comment: can you please elaborate on the criteria used for the deletion? Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: do you want to remove the first line only?

Comment: I think the answer is just right here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710067/deleting-a-specific-line-in-a-file-python

Answer (score 0):

In fact the best solution is not to write before you are not sure. If the data size isn't huge, the simpliest way is to load it to memory, than do whatever you want, than save.

```
lines = []
for x in open("words.txt"):
    lines.append(x)

#do something
#del lines[i] if you don't need them

for x in lines:
    print(x)
```

If the input file is big and you need only the last values to be erasable, you can store only the last values and drop them if you don't need. For saving the last values `collections.deque` is useful. The exact code will depend on the particular logic.

For the only one value to undo you can use this code

```
last_line = None
for x in open("words.txt"):
    if last_line is not None:
        print(last_line)
    last_line = x

    #do something
    #you may use continue or break

    #if you need undo "printing":
    #last_line = None
if last_line is not None:
    print(last_line)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
''.join([ x for x in open('file.txt').readlines() if x.strip() ])
```