# python- How do I delete a line from a text file?

Tags: python, delete-file

I'm a beginner in python and I could use some help. Thank you very much.
I'm confused about how to actually delete a line where you choose the line by input-ing the info.

in my file:

```
PSP0101
PCT0101
PYT0101
```

How do I delete `PSP0101` where I can input `PSP0101` and it will disappear from the file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deleting a specific line in a file (python)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710067/deleting-a-specific-line-in-a-file-python)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `input()` and then open text file in `r+` mode:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r+') as f:
    t = f.read()
    to_delete = input('What should we delete? : ').strip()   # input PSP0101
    f.seek(0)
    for line in t.split('\n'):
        if line != to_delete:
            f.write(line + '\n')
    f.truncate()
```

You can check that this has been performed using a text editor, or python:

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    print(f.read())
```

Output:

```
PCT0101
PYT0101
```