# Pre-process tweets in a JSON file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

I'm following a little article called: **Mining Twitter Data with Python**

Actually, I'm in part 2 that is text pre-processing. This is the example for tokenize a tweet text.

```
import re
import json

emoticons_str = r"""
    (?:
        [:=;] # Eyes
        [oO\-]? # Nose (optional)
        [D\)\]\(\]/\\OpP] # Mouth
    )"""
regex_str = [
    emoticons_str,
    r'<[^>]+>',  # HTML Tags
    r'(?:@[\w_]+)',  # @-mentions
    r"(?:\#+[\w_]+[\w\'_\-]*[\w_]+)",  # hash-tags
    r'http[s]?://(?:[a-z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&amp;+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]))+',  # URLs
    r'(?:(?:\d+,?)+(?:\.?\d+)?)',  # numbers
    r"(?:[a-z][a-z'\-_]+[a-z])",  # words with - and '
    r'(?:[\w_]+)',  # other words
    r'(?:\S)'  # anything else
]

tokens_re = re.compile(r'(' + '|'.join(regex_str) + ')', re.VERBOSE | re.IGNORECASE)
emoticon_re = re.compile(r'^' + emoticons_str + '$', re.VERBOSE | re.IGNORECASE)


def tokenize(s):
    return tokens_re.findall(s)


def preprocess(s, lowercase=False):
    tokens = tokenize(s)
    if lowercase:
        tokens = [token if emoticon_re.search(token) else token.lower() for token in tokens]
    return tokens
```

Now, it works properly when you insert a string directly like this:

```
tweet = 'RT @marcobonzanini: just an example! :D http://example.com #NLP'
print(preprocess(tweet))
```

But once I try to import a JSON for tokenize all tweets text in the file it occurrs an Error.

This is how it's supposed to work.

```
with open('tweets.json', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        tweet = json.loads(line)
        tokens = preprocess(tweet['text'])
```

This is the error displayed:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/fmigg/PycharmProjects/untitled/Data Mining/tweetTextProcessing.py", line 43, in <module>
    tweet = json.loads(line)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py", line 319, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 1)
```

Finally, this is the JSON file called *tweets.json* with Tweets on it (the number of tweets is kinda large, so I'll only put one Tweet in order to analyze the structure of it).

```
{"created_at":"Tue Jun 27 16:05:01 +0000 2017","id":879732307992739840,"id_str":"879732307992739840","text":"RT @PythonQnA: Python List Comprehension Vs. Map #python #list-comprehension #map-function https:\/\/t.co\/YtxeSt64pd","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\/download\/android\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter for Android\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":704974573985525760,"id_str":"704974573985525760","name":"UNIVERSAL TGSI","screen_name":"universaltgsi","location":"Magny-le-Hongre, France, SM","url":"http:\/\/www.tgsi.eu","description":"Find everything you want to know about business Technology by ONE TGSI","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":424,"friends_count":343,"listed_count":273,"favourites_count":4250,"statuses_count":2958,"created_at":"Wed Mar 02 10:20:11 +0000 2016","utc_offset":7200,"time_zone":"Paris","geo_enabled":false,"lang":"fr","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"1B95E0","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/705020861909225472\/psLvMIAP.jpg","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/705020861909225472\/psLvMIAP.jpg","profile_background_tile":true,"profile_link_color":"0084B9","profile_sidebar_border_color":"000000","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"000000","profile_text_color":"000000","profile_use_background_image":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/866410987880099840\/HT8fZKLO_normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/866410987880099840\/HT8fZKLO_normal.jpg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/704974573985525760\/1495404137","default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"retweeted_status":{"created_at":"Tue Jun 27 08:24:00 +0000 2017","id":879616290700263424,"id_str":"879616290700263424","text":"Python List Comprehension Vs. Map #python #list-comprehension #map-function https:\/\/t.co\/YtxeSt64pd","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/jarvis.ratankumar.org\/\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003ePythonQnA\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":747460774998605825,"id_str":"747460774998605825","name":"PythonQnA","screen_name":"PythonQnA","location":"Bengaluru, India","url":null,"description":"I tweet Python questions from stackoverflow.","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":632,"friends_count":64,"listed_count":277,"favourites_count":0,"statuses_count":85791,"created_at":"Mon Jun 27 16:05:10 +0000 2016","utc_offset":null,"time_zone":null,"geo_enabled":false,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"F5F8FA","profile_background_image_url":"","profile_background_image_url_https":"","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_link_color":"1DA1F2","profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/747461193653092352\/Mz9NjeE__normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/747461193653092352\/Mz9NjeE__normal.jpg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/747460774998605825\/1467044067","default_profile":true,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"is_quote_status":false,"retweet_count":2,"favorite_count":1,"entities":{"hashtags":[{"text":"python","indices":[34,41]},{"text":"list","indices":[42,47]},{"text":"map","indices":[62,66]}],"urls":[{"url":"https:\/\/t.co\/YtxeSt64pd","expanded_url":"https:\/\/goo.gl\/OZxWIC","display_url":"goo.gl\/OZxWIC","indices":[76,99]}],"user_mentions":[],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"possibly_sensitive":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"en"},"is_quote_status":false,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[{"text":"python","indices":[49,56]},{"text":"list","indices":[57,62]},{"text":"map","indices":[77,81]}],"urls":[{"url":"https:\/\/t.co\/YtxeSt64pd","expanded_url":"https:\/\/goo.gl\/OZxWIC","display_url":"goo.gl\/OZxWIC","indices":[91,114]}],"user_mentions":[{"screen_name":"PythonQnA","name":"PythonQnA","id":747460774998605825,"id_str":"747460774998605825","indices":[3,13]}],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"possibly_sensitive":true,"filter_level":"low","lang":"en","timestamp_ms":"1498579501518"}
```

I'd like to know why is the reason that this is happening. 
Thank you so much to everyone!

P.S this is the link to the article:
[Mining Twitter Data with Python (Part 2: Text Pre-processing)](https://marcobonzanini.com/2015/03/09/mining-twitter-data-with-python-part-2/)

**UPDATE:**

I tried the code using one simple JSON tweet and two simple JSON tweets in a JSON file and it worked. So it seems that the problem is when I open the entire file with all Tweets on it.

If someone needs that file you can download or watch it in my Microsoft Onedrive.
https://1drv.ms/f/s!AjHPHWCBEuf7ux3uLmSVEaSCPWIE

Comment: I suspect it is because of empty lines in the file. Enclose `json.loads(line)` in try catch and print the invalid line. That should help you find the bad line

Comment: It might be the trailing newline at the end of each line. Try `json.loads(line.strip())`.

Comment: @balki thank you! it worked using this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710067/deleting-a-specific-line-in-a-file-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @balki said, it is because there were empty lines per each JSON object in this pattern:

```
1 JSON Object
2 empty line
3 JSON Object
4 empty line
```

So I took the solution from the following question  [Deleting a specific line in a file (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710067/deleting-a-specific-line-in-a-file-python) and change it to erase empty lines, like this:

```
def erase_empty_lines(file_name):
    file = open(file_name, 'r')
    lines = file.readlines()
    file.close()

    file = open(file_name, 'w')
    for line in lines:
        if line != '\n':
            file.write(line)
    file.close()
```

Comment: If you don't to modify the original file, you can do as follows: https://pastebin.com/p1vdsuds

Answer (score 0):

Your json file has probably only a single line which contains the whole json string. So there is no point in iterating over the lines of the file. Instead you want to load the content of the json file via `tweets = json.load(f)`. Assuming that the different tweets are stored in a list you can iterate over them like that:

```
with open('tweets.json') as fp:
    tweets = json.load(fp)

for tweet in tweets:
    tokens = preprocess(tweet['text'])
```