# Delete all rows with specific values from csv file

Tags: python, csv, data-cleaning

I am working on a problem in which I have a very large dataset in the form of a csv file. This csv file has various columns, one of which is state code. The dataset is significantly larger than I need it to be- I just need the values from one state.

A solution I was thinking of using would be to read in the csv file using Python and then write to a new file with just the rows that I need- removing 49 of the 50 states (U.S).

The csv file has 3million+ rows. I am new to Python and I am not sure how I can effectively do this, what are the best ways to complete this task?

Thank you for your help and I apologize if this seems like a simple question- I am new to Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting all the rows is different from extracting just the one state. Deleting lines from files is dealt with sufficiently [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710067/using-python-for-deleting-a-specific-line-in-a-file). Assuming what you want is to extract just the one state, here's one way you could do it.

```
with open("file.csv", "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        sline = line.split(",")
        if sline[n] == statecode:
            # Where n is the position of the statecode column zero indexed
            # and statecode is your target state code
            pass # this is where you do something with the data
```

With this pattern you implement pretty much any solution that involves incrementing through the csv line by line. This includes writing to a new csv, working with the data in memory, `pandas` or `dask` solutions, and so on.

Your system very may well be able to handle just directly importing to `pandas` or `dask` if that's what you want. These are popular data munging python tools with built-in `read_csv` methods.

Comment: You could also just use the `csv` library to read in the file.

Comment: Absolutely @roadrunner

Answer (score 1):

Regarding processing a large amount of data in Python, one of the most recommended library is [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/). It is a Python library, specialized for data analysis, and is able to parse through a large amount of data using DataFrame object.