# Delete line from file A after it is written to file B. or Move line from file A to new file B after a certain point

Tags: python

I have a file A having content as follows

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
```

1. I read file A
2. I copy file A content to new file B from line 4
3. At the output I need file A as,

   ```
   line1
   line2
   line3
   ```

   and file B as

   ```
   line4
   line5
   ```

I have a code that copies line from A to B but can't figure out how to delete it after writing it to other file ?

Comment: This isnb't a free programming site.  This is the most basic of programming problems.  Give it a try yourself.  Show us what you've tried if it isn't working out for you.

Comment: You need to rewrite file A, containing only the lines you want in it.

Comment: Thank you mkrieger, will try that

Comment: @mkrieger1: Or if they can uniquely identify the split point at the time they reach it, they could use `tell` to remember where it was, and after copying the data to file B, `seek` back and then call `truncate` (which avoids needing to rewrite the file at all). Assumes the data to "move" is always at the end of the file of course.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I agree. Still...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using Python for deleting a specific line in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710067/using-python-for-deleting-a-specific-line-in-a-file)

Answer (score 0):

If you can identify when you're at the split point (the point where the data to stay in file A ends, and the data to move in file B begins), and the data to move is "the rest of the file", the best approach is to `truncate` file A after copying the excess data.

Pseudo-code for it would be:

```
moving = False
splitpoint = None
for line in infile:  # infile must have been opened in r+ mode to allow modification
    if moving:
        outfile.write(line)
    elif should_start_moving():
        # Assumes you know you're at the split point when you have read line 3,
        # before you see line 4
        splitpoint = infile.tell()  # Save off split point
        moving = True

# If we ever reached the splitpoint, we want to truncate what we moved
if splitpoint is not None:
    infile.seek(splitpoint)  # Go back to where we saw the split point
    infile.truncate()        # Cut off the rest of the file
```