# How to delete rows in an excel file with csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, tkinter

Sorry for dragging the entire thread for a millennium and making it way too unsolvable, but I have solved majority of the problems, it's just that I want to fix my delete code but I have no idea where to start with it.

```
def delete_record():
    with open('StudentDetails.csv', 'wb',) as csvfile:
         csvFileWriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
         a = delete_student_entry.get()
         b = delete_password_entry.get()
         csvFileWriter.writerow([a,b])
```

I want the program to take the input from the entry box in the window (as I am using Tkinter) and delete an entire row from the input. I will welcome any rewrites of the code as it will be a subroutine for my "delete student" menu (unconventional, I know, but using other forms of calling the subroutine will result in an error in which I had no choice but to do so...)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean deleting the row, which you get from your Entries, from your CSV file?
If so your answer can be found here:
[using Python for deleting a specific line in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710067/using-python-for-deleting-a-specific-line-in-a-file)

Comment: Hi, I have tried using the answers in the thread but I don't think it's what I'm looking for. I'm trying to utilize the csv library, but I have only found out how to add new rows, not delete them...