# I want to be able to delete a specific line in this text file

Tags: python

I have the following code which must delete a specific line in the text file `notes.txt`:

```
f = open("notes.txt","r+")

notestext = f.read()

print("NOTES:")

print(notestext)

enter = input("Press enter to add or change notes \n")

print("Type delete to delete a note or add to add a note")

start = input()
if start == "add":
    notetoadd = input("Type your note to add \n")
    f.write("\n")
    f.write(notetoadd)
```

Here is the problem, i dunno what to put here:

```
if start == "delete":
    notetodelete = input("Type the note you want to delete \n")
f.close()
```

Comment: Can you provide the text file you're using, perhaps via Pastebin or a similar service?

Comment: This post answers how to remove a line from a text file. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710067/using-python-for-deleting-a-specific-line-in-a-file

Answer (score 0):

Search for the note you want to delete using the string.index() method. You can then use string.replace() method to get your string after it gets deleted

Comment: You missed the important part: changing the file content.