# How to delete a line from a separate file using python

Tags: python

```
def editTodo():
    with open ("todolist", "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            data = line.strip()
            print(f'{data}\n')
            deletion = input("What do you want to delete?")
            if deletion in data:
                with open("todolist") as f:
                    lines = f.read().splitlines()
                    lines.remove()
                print ("Successfully deleted")
```

This is my function for a to do list to edit their to do list. I want the user to be able to delete one of the items from their todo list but I am getting this error. `TypeError: remove() takes exactly one argument (0 given)` I am pretty sure there are other errors too, sorry about that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [using Python for deleting a specific line in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710067/using-python-for-deleting-a-specific-line-in-a-file)

Answer (score 1):

you should get rid of the second fileopen. Iterate through lines, ask if user wants to delete. After the loop, write remaining stuff in lines to the same filename.

```
def editTodo():
    with open ("todolist", "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    index = 0
    while index < len(lines):
        current_event = lines[index].strip()
        print(current_event)
        deletion = input('what do you want to delete? use white space to seperate events').split(' ')
        # convert current_event to a list of things, 
        # then filter against stuff user wants to delete
        current_event = current_event.split(' ')
        current_event = list(filter(lambda item: item not in deletion, current_event))
        lindex[index] = ' '.join(current_event)
        index += 1 
    # now that we've filtered out events we deleted, write the file again
    with open('name.txt', 'w') as fileout:
        [fileout.write(item+'\n') for item in lines]
```

Comment: You should show OP how to do that with code, or post this as a comment.