# How to delete only one line containing a specific keyword? And save that line into another file

Tags: python

```
fileHandler = editFile(warehouse,'r')
fileHandler2 = open('provided_parts.txt','w')
```

Here I am prompting user to select the part name from a number list, and then retrieving the part name

```
output = []
for part in range(quantityOfParts):
    part = partSelection()
    partName = partsList[part-1]
```

This section doesn't seem to be working, I am trying to only delete one line in .txt file that contains the part name, and then saving that line into another file (`fileHandler2`)

```
for line in fileHandler:
    line = line.rstrip()
    newLine = line.split('\t')
    if partName.lower() == newLine[0].lower():
        fileHandler2.write(newLine[0])
        fileHandler2.write('\n')
        newLine[0] = '\t'
    output.append(newLine)

fileHandler.close()
fileHandler2.close()

fHand = editFile(warehouse,'w')

for part in output:
    for p in part:
        fHand.write(p)
        fHand.write('\t')
    fHand.write('\n')

fHand.close()
```

Comment: Please be very specific — "doesn't seem to be working" is too vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example below implies that specific word is wrapped by spaces. if you want it to be case-sensitive, remove `.lower()`

```py
line_to_be_deleted = "Hello"

fileHandler = open(warehouse, 'rw')
fileHandler2 = open('provided_parts.txt','w')

fileHandler_lines = fileHandler.readlines()
for line in fileHandler_lines:
    # write all lines except one that should be removed
    if line_to_be_deleted.lower() not in line.strip('\n').lower():
        fileHandler.write(line)
    else:
        # then write removed line into second file
        fileHandler2.write(line)

# do not forget to close files
fileHandler.close()
fileHandler2.close()
```

[References](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4710090/8485707)

Comment: This solved my problem. However, fileHandler should be open under 'r' as .readlines() function would not work with 'w'.

Comment: @JackChong `rw` in that case, because script overwrites its content