# How to delete a specific word by using len() in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I saw too much question here no one answered my question.
I have text file *ckb.txt* :

```
چ
چۆنی
باشی
سوپاس
ئاسمان
یاسا
دەنگ
چنار
کورستانی گەورە
```

I want to remove any line which *len()* is more than 4 characters, I wrote this simple code but not working, Any suggestion or tip?

```
    import arabic_reshaper
    from bidi.algorithm import get_display
    import unicodedata

    with open("ckb.txt", 'r+', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    
        g = f.readlines()
        for line in g:
            print(get_display(arabic_reshaper.reshape(line)))
            print(len(line))
            if len(line) > 4:
                del line
```

Comment: What do you mean by "remove"? from the file? from a variable? What do you mean by "not working"? What *does* it  do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete a specific line in a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710067/how-to-delete-a-specific-line-in-a-file)

Comment: I think this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/q/4710067/14454560

Comment: @Sayse i want to delete the word when the condition is true.

Comment: @Tomerikoo I already saw this but it's better if you have specific word not checking all words to delete the one that condition not applied.

Comment: In the accepted answer, you just need to change `if line.strip("\n") != "nickname_to_delete":` to `if len(line) < 4:`...

Comment: @Tomerikoo Let's you have a file have 5 line each of them have a word, if you want to delete the line that have word which its characters is more than 4 .

Comment: Delete from *what*?

Comment: Again, the accepted answer in the link is the answer you're looking for, with the change I wrote above... Please close this question as duplicate

Comment: @Tomerikoo I did but deleted all the lines.

Comment: Try `if len(line.strip()) < 4:`. Otherwise, all your lines are `>= 4`...

Comment: @Tomerikoo I know this should solve it but it deletes all the lines and make it emplty file.
my words are not all more than 4 as you can see first one is 1 character last one is 15 i think.

Comment: Well that's as far as I can help man... Maybe it has something to do with the arabic characters? I can't reproduce as they are being copied as squares...

Comment: @Tomerikoo If you mean python they should be encode it with utf-8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with open("ckb.txt", 'r+', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

with open("ckb.txt", 'w+', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    lines = list(filter(lambda x: len(x) <= 4, lines))
    f.writelines(lines)
```

Comment: It deltes all the lines in the .txt.

Comment: @Jwtiyar there is a typo: `x` should be `lines` in `lines = list(filter(..., x))`

Comment: @Tomerikoo I already knew that i should change it, but i was typing line not lines. this solved the problem. Thank you again.

Answer (score 3):

Based on this:
[How to delete a specific line in a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710067/how-to-delete-a-specific-line-in-a-file)

```
import arabic_reshaper
from bidi.algorithm import get_display
import unicodedata

with open("ckb.txt", 'r+', encoding='utf-8') as f:

    g = f.readlines()
    f.seek(0)
    for line in g:
        print(get_display(arabic_reshaper.reshape(line)))
        print(len(line))
        if len(line.strip("\n")) <= 4:
            f.write(line)
    f.truncate()
```

Comment: It adds all the line agian and again

Comment: That's not what is asked for... OP wants to **delete** lines, not add them again

Comment: After you do `f.readlines()` the file pointer is at the end of the file... Then every following `write` just adds lines at the end of the file. The final `f.truncate` does nothing... Maybe you meant to do: `g = f.readlines(); f.seek(0); f.truncate()` and the rest stays the same. That would work...

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
lines = [line for line in open("ckb.txt", 'r+', encoding='utf-8').readlines() if len(line) < 4]
```

Use it directly after importing libraries.

If you want to write back these lines in original file, use:

```
with open("ckb.txt", 'w', encoding='utf-8'):
    f.write('\n'.join(lines))
```

Comment: How it deletes the line which larger than 4 character?

Comment: It reads lines and only adds those which match criteria. Once you have them filtered, write them back in original file

Comment: You don't actually need the `.readlines()` there... Looping over a file descriptor already iterates the line