# How to find and check for a specific word in a file and then delete it

Tags: python, file

My text has student data in the form of 1234:zakasi:2:1:3 (student id ,name , sem ,yrs , courses)

I wanted to first check if the student id is in the file and then delete the entire line the id is in if it is

```
infile = open("students.dat","r")
f = infile.readlines()
id = input('enter your id:')
new_list = []
for line in f:
    for item in line.split(':'):
    new_list.append(item)
    if id in new_list[0]:
        # delete the line its found in
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete a specific line in a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710067/how-to-delete-a-specific-line-in-a-file)

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("students.dat","r") as infile:
f = infile.readlines()
student_id = input('enter your id:')
new_list = []
lines_kept = []
for line in f:
    for item in line.split(':'):
    new_list.append(item)
    if student_id in new_list[0]:
        # delete the line its found in
        print("Found instance")
    else:
        lines_kept.append(line)


# Writing part
with open("students.dat","w") as outfile:
    outfile.write("\n".join(lines_kept))
```